# Get row index of table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the index of a  element within the following table when the user clicks on a row.

```
    <table class="table table-hover" id="event_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event Title</th>
        <th>Event Location</th>
        <th>Event Time</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td>Gathering</td>
          <td>City Centre</td>
          <td>10:30</td>
          <td>10/09/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Meetup</td>
          <td>Some place</td>
          <td>12:30</td>
          <td>15/09/2016</td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
```

How would I do this with jQuery?
I have tried something similar to this:

```
$("#event_table tbody tr").on("click", function() {
   $(this).index(); 
});
```

Comment: Your syntax is a little off: `$(this).index()`. And if you want to see it, call `alert` or `console.log`.

Comment: maybe some errors in console?

Comment: Yeah i've tried to log/ alert it, nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works just fine:

```js
$("#event_table").on("click", "tbody tr", function() {
   alert($(this).index()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="event_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event Title</th>
        <th>Event Location</th>
        <th>Event Time</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Gathering</td>
          <td>City Centre</td>
          <td>10:30</td>
          <td>10/09/2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Meetup</td>
          <td>Some place</td>
          <td>12:30</td>
          <td>15/09/2016</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thats weird, i've spent the past hour debugging and it wont work. The table is being loaded dynamically, could have something to do with that. Il go check.

Comment: Yeah so I figured it out, because it was loaded dynamically I needed to add the `on("click", function() {...})` after the new rows were added.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to care about the sequence. I've updated the js code snippet. It should work on ajax loaded `tr`s as well.